# Trying to edit static variable of parent A class for all child class B

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, casting, static-variables

I have a problem with a static variable within a class.
I'm trying to edit a static variable of a child class without editing the others childs class static variable.

The header file :

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}

    void printName() {qDebug() << _name; }    
    void changeName(QString name) {_name = name;}

private:
    static QString _name;
};
QString A::_name = QString("default");

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A() {}
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C() : A() {}    
};
```

I'm trying to edit the static _name of my class B without editing the _name of my class C. When I try this code in this main.cpp :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A *a = new B{};
    A *b = new B{};
    A *c = new C{};

    a->printName();
    b->printName();
    c->printName();

    B *tmp = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    tmp->changeName("new");

    qDebug() << "Then";    

    a->printName();
    b->printName();
    c->printName();
}
```

Here's what I have :

```
"default"
"default"
"default"
Then
"new"
"new"
"new"
```

Anyone has any idea on how I could fix this ?

Here's what I've also try :

```
class A {
    public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    void printName() {qDebug() << _name; }

    virtual void changeName(QString name) {_name = name;}
    private:
    static QString _name;
};

QString A::_name = QString("default");

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A() {}

    void changeName(QString name) override {_name = name;}
private:
    static QString _name;
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C() : A() {}

    void changeName(QString name) override {_name = name;}
private:
    static QString _name;
};
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux There is no other solutions ? Because I have a lot a child class ... Would be a shame to create the same static member in each child class

Comment: Why is it `static`?

Comment: It's static because I want this variable to be the same in my child class B at any moment.

Comment: @starkmax If you want different values for each child class, you need different variables to hold the values. Currently there is only one variable. That's what `static` class variables are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one `A::_name`, it can only have one value at any given time. Since all your derived types uses the same `static` member they necessarily all have the same `_name` value. To fix this, each derived type must provide it's own `static` member instead.

To avoid repeating the same members in every derived type, you can define them in a templated intermediate class that sits between `A` and the derived types `B` and `C`. Each template specialization has it's own `static` member. So, provided each derived type supplies a unique value to the intermediate type's template argument, they will have their own names. For example, split `A` into two classes :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    virtual void printName() = 0;
    virtual void changeName(std::string name) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class A_impl : public A
{
public:
    void printName() override { 
        std::cout << _name << '\n';
    };
    void changeName(std::string name) override { 
        _name = std::move(name);
    };

private:
    static std::string _name;
};

template<class T>
std::string A_impl<T>::_name = "default";
```

Then each derived type should inherit from `A_impl` instead of `A`. By providing their own type to `A_impl`, you can be sure each derived type provides a unique template argument :

```
class B : public A_impl<B> { };

class C : public A_impl<C> { };
```

Now your test should print

```
default
default
default
Then
new
new
default
```

Comment: Thx ! That's exactly what I was searching.